# How can I find all of a page's publishing history for a given period of time?

Tags: publishing, 2009

In Tridion 2009, is there any way to find all the publishing history for a page for a specific period of time?

I tried to get this information from the Transactions table but it overrides the value every time the status is changed.

Is there any way to get this information from somewhere within the standard Tridion architecture (like the CM Database?) I guess it is not possible to get from the queue as that points to the Transactions table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this information is not available anywhere in Tridion. Only the most recent publish/unpublish information is stored in Tridion.

Comment: Thanks for your clear input, as new implementation in event system is not possible as of now in our case.

Answer (score 7):

You are right, the Publishing Queue only stores the most recent publish action for an item. The best way to get this information is to capture it in a custom database using the Event System. You can implement an event with the following signature:

```
EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<RepositoryLocalObject, SetPublishStateEventArgs>
  (ItemFinishedPublishing, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
```

..and implement your delegate method: `ItemFinishedPublishing` to capture whatever information you require.

Note that this event is triggered only after successful publish/unpublish of an individual item (Page, Component, Taxonomy). If you want to have information about the whole publish transaction, you will need to investigate the following event signature:

```
EventSystem.SubscribeAsync<PublishTransaction, SaveEventArgs>
  (TransactionSaved, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted);
```

Note that this event is triggered multiple times per transaction, as it goes through all the states (Queued for Publishing, Waiting for Transport, Deploying etc.), so you probably only want to log stuff for the end states; `Success`, `Warning`, `Failure`.

Comment: We may go for this suggestion in future, as of now its not possible in pour case. But, many thanks for your detailed explanation on this.